# run shell script from where it stopped execution

Tags: bash, shell

I've bash script written to read each line of a file which has commands and execute them one by one and stops when a command fails.

```
while read -r line
do
$line || exit 1
done< /root/ansi-pb/sample.txt
```

sample.txt has following commands

```
echo "hello world"
free -m
mvn -version
date
echo "bye"
```

I want to improvise this script, so If I encounter any failed command I would correct it in text file and when I rerun the script it should start only from failed command but not from the beginning

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513767/rerun-shell-script-only-from-failed-command

Comment: "guarded commands" is one way to write something that can be rerun without there being issues from subsequent re-runs

Comment: Your posted script seems to implement `bash -e /root/ansi-pb/sample.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0 $$"
##Here do your stuff and redirect the errors to a log file
##if an error is found say using $?, use the following
kill -SIGSTOP $$
##After you'r done correcting your file
##use kill -SIGCONT <pid> on a console, the process shall continue
## Put in a mechanism to retry the last executed command 
echo "I am done!!! after SIGSTOP $$"
exit 0
```

This is just an example, you could implement this in your way according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This sets an `ERR` trap:

```
trap 'printf "Error for %s, halted, continue with fg\n" "$cmd"; kill -s STOP $$; continue' ERR

while IFS= read -r cmd; do
    command $cmd
done <input
```

The trap is triggered by any error that would usually cause the script to fail when run under `set -e`.  The trap will print an informational message and then stop the process temporarily.

When the user resumes it with `fg`, the `continue` statement in the trap ensures that the next line of input is read.

While the script is suspended, one may edit the input file. The script will continue reading from the next line of input after the line containing the failed command.